# Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, url, import, change-password

I want to use the default django.contrib.auth.views for resetting passwords with email confirmation. All this code is on urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'houses'

urlpatterns = [

    # Root and details page
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<house_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.view_house, name='index'),

    # Register / login / logout
    url(r'^register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_user, name='logout_user'),

    # User profiles and edit profiles
    url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
    url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),

    # ---- ERRORS ARE HERE ---- change / reset passwords 
    url(r'^change_password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
    url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset,
        {'post_reset_redirect': 'houses:password_reset_done',}, name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password_reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
        auth_views.password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),

]
```

No matter what I try i keep getting:

```
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Is it because my app name is houses? I've been trying things for hours with no luck.

Comment: Try with 'houses: password_reset_confirm' .  like '<app name>:<url name>'

Answer (score 2):

This error is because Django expects to find the url password_reset_complete in the project urls and not in the app urls, so for you to keep that url in the app you need to rewrite the template password_template_email.html and passes it in the url password_reset pass the param email_template_name:

```
path('reset_password/',
 auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name="users/registration/password_reset.html",
        email_template_name = 'users/registration/password_reset_email.html',
        success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_done')),
    name="reset_password"),
```

and in the template password_reset_email, pass

```
{% autoescape off %}
To initiate the password reset process for your Account {{ user.email }},
click the link below:

{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'youapp:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}

If clicking the link above doesn't work, please copy and paste the URL in a new browser
window instead.

{% endautoescape %}
```

I hope I helped!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using reverse url in template

```
{% url 'houses:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=<uidb64> token=<token> %}
```

and if you using reverse url in python code then use

```
reverse('houses:password_reset_confirm', args=(<uidb64>,<token>,))
```

Here, <`uidb64`> means `uidb64` value
      <`token`> means `token` value

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error before, to fix this I just wrote the URLs of the reset password option in the main URLs file **(project_name/urls.py)** and I've add in the templates folder a folder named "**registration**" that has inside a file named `password_reset_email.html` ( it contains the email that will be sent to the user, something like:

```
{% autoescape off %}
To initiate the password reset process for your Account {{ user.email }},
click the link below:

{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}

If clicking the link above doesn't work, please copy and paste the URL in a new browser
window instead.

{% endautoescape %}
```

). you can check my code on github if you want to see it clearly https://github.com/Ninou01/customer-relationship-management-system/blob/master/crm1/urls.py